# Mps set Breakpoint in Language Definition

Tags: debugging, mps

How do you correctly debug your language creation ?

In particular i want to test a scoping-constraint and look at the content of the nodes. You can set Breakpoint in the constraint-file but they are never triggerd. Same goes for print messages.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to follow the instructions at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD33/Using+MPS+Debugger#UsingMPSDebugger-Debugginglanguagedefinitions

Admittedly, it requires quite some effort to setup, so frequently tracing output gives quicker insight.

Comment: I get a "ModuleWithSuchNameAlreadyExistsInTheRepositoryException: Trying to register a module with the name Evaluation Container Module at null : module with the same name already exists at null" exception if i try this (MPS 3.3)

Comment: You must check the checkbox "open current project" or open a different project in the new MPS instance, not the original one.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did everything in the tutorial including that step, i even tried to copy the virtual machine parameter, but i always get this error